# How to get results with angular.js $http?

Tags: angularjs, routes, anchor, angularjs-routing

I'm getting some problem getting the results from my api server with angularjs.

This is my code:

**home.html (view)**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>

        <p>{{ message }}</p>

        <a href="#" ng-click="getOrders()">Orders!</a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="order in orders">{{order}}</li>
</ul>
```

**main.js (controller)**

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    $scope.orders = [];
    $scope.getOrders = function(){
        $http.get('http://apidemo.dev/api/orders').success(function(response){
            console.log("My data: " + response);
            $scope.orders = response;
        });
    }
});
```

When I click the button, I can see the results in the console, but not in the list.

If use this code in the controller, it works when it loads, and when I click the button:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    $http.get('http://apidemo.dev/api/orders').success(function(response){
        console.log("My data: " + response);
        $scope.orders = response;
    });
    $scope.getOrders = function(){
        $http.get('http://apidemo.dev/api/orders').success(function(response){
            console.log("My data: " + response);
            $scope.orders = response;
        });
    }
});
```

What is the problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Should work... can you post what `response` is?

Comment: .success is deprecated, use then. Aside from that, did you consider the fact that your calls are async?

Comment: I usually would initialize $scope.orders as an empty array right below $scope.message because sometimes it seems like angular makes assumptions about things not yet declared in the scope object in cases like these.  Worth a try, I guess?

Comment: I've tried it with: $scope.orders = []; below $scope.message but It doesn't work.

Comment: @Klian are you using `ng-route`? seems like you are redirecting to blank page while you have `href="#"` in it

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar !

Comment: @Klian take a look at mine answer...I've added it.don't forgot to click up arrow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you were using `ngRoute` and you have `href="#"` in your anchor, which leads you redirection to blank page, Keep `href=""` will help you in css to show `pointer: cursor;` on hover of it

**Button**

```
<a href="" ng-click="getOrders()">Orders!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your help.

The problem was the link in the view...

```
<a href="#" ng-click="getOrders()">Orders!</a>
```

would be:

```
<a ng-click="getOrders()">Orders!</a>
```